# How do you read a UTF8 Arabic text file in Metro?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, file-io, utf-8, microsoft-metro

I'm using the following code to read the contents of the text file. The file is encoded in some sort of Utf8 format:

```
String File = "ms-appx:///Arabic/file.txt";
contents = await Windows.Storage.PathIO.ReadTextAsync(File, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
```

But the above gives me the error:

```
WinRT information: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had [a similar issue](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/09/winrt-argumentoutofrangeexception-no.html) trying to read text files that contained certain characters (’, °, –) in a file that was using "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252" encoding.

The solution in my case was to force Visual Studio to save the files using UTF-8 encoding.

1. Open the file in Visual Studio
2. File > Advanced Save Options... >
3. Change the encoding to "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"
4. Save the file

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx):

```
StorageFolder folder = 
                      Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("ms-appx:///Arabic/file.txt");

var stream = (await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));

Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader mreader = 
              new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream.GetInputStreamAt(0));

byte[] dgram = new byte[file.Size];

await mreader.LoadAsync((uint)dgram.Length);

mreader.ReadBytes(dgram);
```

Hope it helps.